# Converting audio files(.3gp) to video with Album cover and uploading to YouTube

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I have an audio file in .3gp format on my Android device which I wish
to upload to YouTube. I know that YouTube is a video upload site and
that I need to convert this sound file to video.

I just want an image to display all the time the audio is playing.

Google tells me there are number of tools that can help me. But I want
to do this via java code from my Android device.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I thought the 3gp format supported video too? I am sure I had an old phone that stored all it's sound, video and camera files as 3gp.

Comment: so are you saying I can upload a 3gp audio directly onto YouTube and it will not know the difference? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools such as [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) available for free that allow you to, essentially, mix and convert heterogenous streams. That is you can add a bitmap to a video, create video from slide shows and then add sound etc.  (See a related question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132774/add-an-image-to-mp3-and-convert-it-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg)).

These programs can be executed from within java applications by making Runtime.exec(..) calls.

Answer (score 1):

Sun has an example for stitching multiple JPEGs together into a movie, you can find it [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/JpegImagesToMovie.java).  You should be able to take this example, (its fairly robust), and add what you need to it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into the [**Java Media Framework**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/index.jsp) ([FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jmf/2.1.1/faq-jmf.html))

You can find a vast collection of sample applets/code at the Sun [**Solutions**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/index.html) page.  You can find the API on [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/reference/api/index.html).  I do hope this is compatible on the Android platform, as I haven't had any personal experience developing for it.  But it might be a good place to start.