# ffmpeg command to convert jpg and mp3 to a video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, jpeg

I want to convert a song and jpg file into a mpg video. What is the exact command for that.
I tried this one [Add an image to mp3, and convert it to a video file using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132774/add-an-image-to-mp3-and-convert-it-to-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg), but couldnt understand what is loop input and things.

Help will be appreciated.

Parminder

Comment: why the hell down score. dont you understand its a question.